# Flux.create() not generating events

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, eventsource

I'm trying to use Flux to generate asynchronous server sent events using Flux.create. When my client connects the request eventually times out with no event ever received.  I hard-coded in an event to be sent by the Flux.create just to see data flow, but still nothing received client side.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/stream", headers = "Accept=*/*", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<ServerSentEvent<PricingDTO>> getEventStream() {

  final Flux<ServerSentEvent<PricingDTO>> flux = Flux.<ServerSentEvent<PricingDTO>>create(emitter -> {
    final PricingDTO pricing = new PricingDTO();
    pricing.setId(99L);
    emitter.next(ServerSentEvent.builder(pricing).build());
  });

  return flux;
}
```

Client side (Angular) code:

```
const eventSource = new EventSource(url);
eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
  console.debug('Received event: ' + event);
  const json = JSON.parse(event.data);
  // Should be PricingDTO record here
};

eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
  if (eventSource.readyState === EventSource.CLOSED) {
    console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
    eventSource.close();
  } else {
    console.log('Error here: ' + error);
  }
};
```

I never see an event come through the EventSource.  Eventually the request times out and I see the error: `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

I'm new to using WebFlux and I suspect I'm missing some initialization on the FluxStream before I return the Flux result. I have debugged and do see the request being received by my web service and the Flux object being returned. Any idea why I'm not receiving my events?

Answer (score 1):

Your webflux code seems fine. I tested this with the following simplified example (without your custom classes).

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> getEventStream() {
        return Flux.create(emitter -> emitter.next("hi").next("hi2"));
    }
}
```

When connecting to the steam in chrome you get to see the events coming in just fine:

```
data:hi

data:hi2
```

the problem either lies in your accept header filter, or on the client side. You could ofcourse validate this by connecting to your stream in a browser (or better, a test)